# Warnings from clang-tidy

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

When testing a class, clang-tidy started giving warnings like this. What are they and how to remove them?

```
warning: invalid configuration value '0' for option 'cppcoreguidelines-pro-bounds-constant-array-index.IncludeStyle' [clang-tidy-config]
warning: invalid configuration value '0' for option 'modernize-make-shared.IncludeStyle' [clang-tidy-config]
warning: invalid configuration value '0' for option 'modernize-make-unique.IncludeStyle' [clang-tidy-config]
/home/rumeone/STP/STP2/rgr-rumeone/test/testMatrix.cpp:4:1: warning: initialization of 'test_info_' with static storage duration may throw an exception that cannot be caught [cert-err58-cpp]
TEST(testMatrixConstructor, testCopyConstructor)
^
/home/rumeone/STP/STP2/rgr-rumeone/build/Debug/_deps/googletest-src/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h:2353:42: note: expanded from macro 'TEST'
#define TEST(test_suite_name, test_name) GTEST_TEST(test_suite_name, test_name)
                                         ^
/home/rumeone/STP/STP2/rgr-rumeone/build/Debug/_deps/googletest-src/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h:2347:3: note: expanded from macro 'GTEST_TEST'
  GTEST_TEST_(test_suite_name, test_name, ::testing::Test, \
```

Comment: Have you tried [putting those keywords into Google](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/cert-err58-cpp.html)?

Comment: Yes, I read it. As I understand it, he swears at the GTEST library itself, and not at my written code?

Comment: You have invalid tidy config and you have GTest which tidy doesn't like very much. Yes it will warn about GTest code which is behind macros and no, you can't do anything with it except disabling the warnings.

Comment: Run clang-tidy on your production code rather than on UT